# Problems passing cmd line arguments to program using lein

Tags: clojure

I'm somewhat new to clojure but I'm a very experienced programmer.

I've written a clojure program to process and rate XMLTV listings (for personal use). The program works fine. It also loads rules written as clojure statements in run time and executes them. I've read that that means that I can't "pre-compile" my program and that I have to run it through the REPL (like this `"java -cp clojure-1.4.0.jar clojure-1.4.0.jar my-core.clj my-args"`). If this is wrong, please correct me.

The thing is that when I run this in windows, my "main" function in my-core.clj gets the command line just fine, but when I try to run it under Ubuntu 12.04, it either complains about not finding clojure/main or my functions. Not being one to give up, I tried `"lein run my-args"` (the project is built with Leiningen) but my program gets nil as *command-line*.

I've also tried `-m namespace/func` with the same result.

I'm using Leiningen 1.7.1 and Java 1.6.0_24 OpenJDK Client VM

Anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Regards
Soren Svensson

---

**Thanks!**

I made 3 changes,

1) I added `(:gen-class)`

2) I added a:

```
(defn -main [cmd-line]
    (println (type cmd-line))
    (println cmd-line)
    (println (type command-line-args))
    (println command-line-args))
```

3) I ran `(compile 'xmltvproc.core)` from REPL

before, I ended core.clj with a call to my "main" function `(run-it *command-line-args*)`.
My test with -main showed that cmd-line IS the command line but *command-line-args* is nil.

Running it with `lein run arg1 arg2` now works but when I try `java -cp ...` it still fails.

```
java -cp ./lib/clojure.jar ./classes/xmltvproc/core arg1 arg2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: //classes/xmltvproc/core

java -cp ./lib/clojure.jar xmltvproc.core arg1 arg2
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: clojure/lang/IFn
```

I've tried all the permutations that I can think of, and the result is always one of the two above.

Here's my project.clj file:

```
(defproject xmltvproc "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
    :description "Convert XMLTV listings to CSV file"
    :main xmltvproc.core
    :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]])
```

and my xmltvproc/classes/xmltvproc have all the expected .class files

??

Comment: java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main /path/to/myscript.clj arg1 arg2 arg3

Comment: if you include your project.clj contents and the line that fails to see the args we can give much more specific answers

Answer (score 0):

I am posting some source code from a project that runs on Linux. This information is what I need to create a program that I can execute.

The following code is for a program that reads in .csv input, maps that data into html "form" parameters; calls an IIS server asking that the data (street addresses) be verified by accumail; and then performs an action upon an answer from the web server.

### First, project.clj: Please note :main

```
(defproject addr-verify "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "TODO: add summary of your project"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.1"]
                 [org.clojure/clojure-contrib "1.2.0"]
                 [clojure-csv/clojure-csv "1.2.4"]
                 [org.clojure/tools.cli "0.1.0"]
                 [clj-http "0.1.3"]]
   :main addr-verify.core)
```

### Next, here is the header of addr-verify/src/addr_verify/core.clj.

Please note the use of (:gen-class).

```
(ns addr-verify.core
  ^{:author "Charles M. Norton",
    :doc "addr-verify is a small Clojure program that 
    runs address verification through the 
     .
     .
     .

   "}

      (:gen-class)
      (:require [clojure.string :as cstr])
      (:require [clojure.contrib.str-utils :as ustr])
      (:require [clj-http.client :as client])
      (:use clojure-csv.core)
      (:use [clojure.tools.cli])
      (:import java.util.Date)
      (:import java.lang.Thread)
      (:import java.io.File))
```

I wind up running lein uberjar, and then I wind up creating a stand-alone executeable from the uberjar.

If this does not help you, please post some source code and a small program.

Don't let Clojure's version give you pause. I'm at home, and have not updated my laptop with new sources in a while.

### Edit:

Here is what I use to parse the command line:

```
; Parses for options passed in on the command line.

(defn parse-opts
  "Using the newer cli library, parses command line args."
  [args]
  (cli args
       (optional ["--in-file-name" ".csv input file" 
           :default "resultset.csv"] identity)
       (optional ["--out-file-name" ".csv pipe delimited output file" 
           :default "accumail_out.unl"] )))

; Main driver of the whole program.
(defn -main 
  [& args]
  (let [opts (parse-opts args)
        start-time (str (Date.))]

  .
  .
  .
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use eval, load, read, load-file, and all the rest of the dynamic compilation code anywhere even if you use the ahead of time compilation. Clojure does not depend on having a java development environment for these features. so you can feel free to AOT compile to your hearts content.

Comment: Thanks for the input, I will try it. Do you know why http://clojure.org/compilation says: "Some reasons to use AOT compilation are: ... To create an application that does not need runtime bytecode generation and custom classloaders"?